# Перенос слов по строкам в меню

Tags: html, строки, css

Доброе время суток. Нужна помощь. Как можно сделать перенос слов на следующую строку, если все слова не умещаются по длине div?

[Сайт с проблемой](http://museum.skynet-centr.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеется в виду пункт 'Премия за мир Евросоюзу ...', то

в css добавьте в `ul#bt_nav_menu li ul li` свойство `white-space:normal`

Comment: Не помогает =(

Answer (score 2):

Задайте ширину `div`, в который заключен список.